WinForms DateTimePicker and Linux Wine
I came across a legacy project that has WinForms and a DateTimePicker with a CheckBox (dateTimePicker1.ShowCheckBox = true). It works fine under Windows, but under Linux (Debian) with Wine (version 8), when the value is programmatically set to false:
private void buttonSetFalse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Before: {this.dateTimePicker1.Value} {this.dateTimePicker1.Checked}");
    
    dateTimePicker1.Checked = false;
    
    MessageBox.Show($"After: {this.dateTimePicker1.Value} {this.dateTimePicker1.Checked}");
}

the checkbox is not turned off and the value remains true. I wonder if there is a hack to fix this?

Not a direct answer, but the WinForms just wraps the native control, provided by the Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-date-and-time-picker-date-and-time-picker-control-reference). Or, in your case, by WINE (see https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/commctrl.h). So, the first thing I'd do is check if the native WINE implementation without the C# wrapper has the same problem. If so, then you may need to fix the WINE or try to workaround by sending some window messages, etc.). If it has not, then you can check the C# wrapper.

Do you mean, when you set that Property to false, the DTP is not updated in the UI (of course, you remove the MessageBoxes for that)? Or just that you cannot read the new value in the same context (the Button_Click handler)?

@Serg I will look towards WinAPI and SendMessage(dtp.Handle, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, new IntPtr(GDT_NONE), ptr);

@Jimi Yes, in the GUI the flag still remains and the value is still true. MessageBox for clarity.

Have you actually removed the MessageBox calls (you should print the information in the Output window, using Debug.WriteLine() or Console.WriteLine(), depending on the configuration of VS)? The DateTime control's handler in Wine calls InvalidateRect() but not UpdateWindow() when the internal SetSystemTime function is called, triggered by the DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME message -- The SendMessage declaration is SendMessage(IntPtr handle, int msg, int wParam, SYSTEMTIME lParam);, so SendMessage(dtp.Handle, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_NONE, null);

I'm not completely sure of the correctness of the decision, however, it helped me like this. Maybe there is something to fix.
public static class DateTimePickerHelper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam
    );

    private const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME = DTM_FIRST + 2;
    private const int GDT_NONE = 1; // DateTimePicker unchecked state

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        public ushort wYear;
        public ushort wMonth;
        public ushort wDayOfWeek;
        public ushort wDay;
        public ushort wHour;
        public ushort wMinute;
        public ushort wSecond;
        public ushort wMilliseconds;
    }

    public static void SetUnchecked(DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(st));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(st, ptr, true);

        // Send DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME message with GDT_NONE to uncheck the checkbox:
        SendMessage(dtp.Handle, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, new IntPtr(GDT_NONE), ptr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}

Custom DateTimePicker:
public class CustomDateTimePicker: DateTimePicker
{
    public new bool Checked
    {
        get => base.Checked;
        set
        {
            base.Checked = value;

            if (!value /*&& IsWine()*/)
            {
                DateTimePickerHelper.SetUnchecked(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

Thus, where DateTimePicker does not work on unchecked, we do it forcibly.
